# How to get Selenium working with PHP/Firefox3 on Linux

Tags: php, testing, selenium, firefox-3

I am trying to get [Selenium RC](http://selenium-rc.openqa.org/tutorial.html) working with Firefox 3 on Linux with PHP/Apache but am experiencing problems.  Here's what I've done:

- I have installed the Firefox Selenium-IDE extension.
- On the web server (which in my case is actually the same machine running Firefox), I've started the Selenium server with: java -jar selenium-server.jar -interactive
- I have a PHP script as follows:

PHP:

```
require_once 'Testing/Selenium.php';

$browser = new Testing_Selenium("*custom /usr/lib/firefox-3.0.3/firefox", "https://www.example.com");
$browser->start();
```

When I run the PHP script, it does launch a new Firefox tab, but **I get this error message**:

```
The requested URL /selenium-server/core/RemoteRunner.html was not found on this server.
```

I have had more success with Firefox 2 (by using `"*firefox"` instead of `"*custom"` but don't want to use that for my current project.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not sure of the etiquette of answering your own question... but having experimented in a trial-and-error way, here's how I've managed to get Selenium working with PHP/Firefox3 on Ubuntu.

1. I downloaded RC and copied the php client directory to /usr/share/php as 'Selenium'
2. I navigated to the Selenium Server directory in the download, and started selenium with `java -jar selenium-server.jar`
3. I created a new Firefox profile (by running firefox -ProfileManager).  I called the new Profile 'Selenium'
4. Within that profile, I editing the Firefox Network preferences to proxy all protocols via localhost port 4444.
5. I created my php script and ran it with this command:

   `php -d include_path=".:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/php/Selenium/PEAR" test.php`

I've listed my (basic, non-PHPUnit, non-OO) first test script below for reference.

```
require_once 'Testing/Selenium.php';

$oSelenium = new Testing_Selenium(
    "*custom /usr/lib/firefox-3.0.3/firefox -P Selenium",
    "https://www.example.com");
$oSelenium->start();

$oSelenium->open("/");

if (!$oSelenium->isElementPresent("id=login_button")) {
        $oSelenium->click("logout");
        $oSelenium->waitForPageToLoad(10000);
        if (!$oSelenium->isElementPresent("id=login_button")) {
                echo "Failed to log out\n\n";
                exit;
        }
}

$oSelenium->type("login", "my_username");
$oSelenium->type("password", "my_password");
$oSelenium->click("login_button");
$oSelenium->waitForPageToLoad(10000);

$oSelenium->click("top_nav_campaigns");

$oSelenium->stop();
```

Answer (score 1):

I use phpunit, selenium RC php api to run my testcases. My testcase looks like

```
1235$Deepan@Newton~/selenium/ide_scripts$
cat mytest.php
 'FF on linux',
      'browser' => '*firefox',
      'host'    => '10.211.55.8',
      'port'    => 4444,
      'timeout' => 30000,
    ),
    array(
      'name'    => 'FF on windows',
      'browser' => '*firefox',
      'host'    => '10.211.55.5',
      'port'    => 4444,
      'timeout' => 30000,
    ),
     */
    array(
      'name'    => 'Google Chrome on windows',
      'browser' => '*googlechrome',
      'host'    => '10.211.55.5',
      'port'    => 4444,
      'timeout' => 30000,
    ),
    /*
    array(
      'name'    => 'IE on windows',
      'browser' => '*iexplore',
      'host'    => '10.211.55.5',
      'port'    => 4444,
      'timeout' => 30000,
    ),
    array(
      'name'    => 'Safari on MacOS X',
      'browser' => '*safari',
      'host'    => 'localhost',
      'port'    => 4444,
      'timeout' => 30000,
    ),
    array(
      'name'    => 'Firefox on MacOS X',
      'browser' => '*chrome',
      'host'    => 'localhost',
      'port'    => 4444,
      'timeout' => 30000,
    ),
     */
    array(
      'name'    => 'Google Chrome on MacOS X',
      'browser' => '*googlechrome',
      'host'    => 'localhost',
      'port'    => 4444,
      'timeout' => 30000,
    )
  );

  protected function setUp()
  {
    //$this->setBrowser("*chrome");
    $this->setBrowserUrl("http://www.facebook.com/");
  }

  public function testMyTestCase()
  {
    $this->open("/index.php?lh=94730c649368393b6954cb9fc0802e0a&eu=iKjrC7Q2aC-8tcU7PVLilg");
    $this->type("email", "myemail@domain.com");
    $this->type("pass", "mypassword");
    $this->click("persistent");
    $this->click("//input[@type='submit']");
    $this->waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    sleep(10);
    $this->open("http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/");
    sleep(4);
    $this->click("link=Play");
    $this->waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    sleep(4);
    $this->click("navAccountLink");
    sleep(4);
    $this->click("link=Logout");
    $this->waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    sleep(4);
  }
}
?>
1332$Deepan@Newton~/selenium/ide_scripts$
phpunit mytest.php
```

This will connect to browsers running inside virtual machines