# How do I get the link element in a html page with PHP

Tags: php, html, dom

First, I know that I can get the HTML of a webpage with:

```
file_get_contents($url);
```

What I am trying to do is get a specific link element in the page (found in the head).

e.g:

```
<link type="text/plain" rel="service" href="/service.txt" /> (the element could close with just >)
```

My question is: How can I get that specific element with the "rel" attribute equal to "service" so I can get the href?

My second question is: Should I also get the "base" element? Does it apply to the "link" element? I am trying to follow the standard.

Also, the html might have errors. I don't have control on how my users code there stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using PHP's [`DOMDocument`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), this should do it (untested):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($file);
$head = $doc->getElementsByTagName('head')->item(0);
$links = $head->getElementsByTagName("link");
foreach($links as $l) {
    if($l->getAttribute("rel") == "service") {
        echo $l->getAttribute("href");
    }
}
```

Comment: Not loadHTMLFile but loadHTML (I wanted to loaded from a web page) $head.get[...] -> $head->get[...] Anyways, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should get the Base element, but know how it works and its scope.

In truth, when I have to screen-scrape, I use phpquery.  This is an older PHP port of jQuery... and what that may sound like something of a dumb concept, it is awesome for document traversal... and doesn't require well-formed XHTMl.

http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) under Java for Web-Application-Testing. It provides very nice features for document traversal using CSS-Selectors.

Have a look at [How to use Selenium with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166941/how-to-get-selenium-working-with-php-firefox3-on-linux).
But this setup might be to complex for your needs if you only want to extract this one link.